# PyQt Browser blocks code execution

Tags: python, browser, pyqt, pyqt5

I have added PyQt5 Browser to my project but when `show()` method is executed, it blocks the codes following it. Is there a way, not show it as modal, or have it run on another thread?

This is the code I have taken from Python Tutorials site, which works perfect, but just blocks the code on `show()`:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebKit import *
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

web = QWebView()
web.load(QUrl("https://pythonspot.com"))
web.show() 
# the code in here won't run while the form web.show() opened, is not closed
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What do you mean by "blocks the code"? What code are you referring to? Are you talking about the event-loop? GUI programs are event-driven. You need to write code that responds to events from the system and user interaction.

Comment: @ekhumoro this code will work on a device that sends the device location periodically every second (which already works). and the user sees map and some data in a browser. so after the browser is shown, there is a infinite loop that reads location and posts it, but this code does not work when `show()` method is executed. unless the form that it opens is closed

Comment: The tasks that consume time block the GUI, those tasks must be worked on by another thread, and send the data to the GUI thread through signals.

Comment: @eyllanesc could you show a small example on how it is done?

Comment: see this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46869472/how-to-apply-pyqt-qthread-on-this-piece-of-code/46869834#46869834

Comment: and this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46859945/linking-live-data-from-an-arduino-to-a-lcdnumber-from-pyqt5-with-python3-5/46860282#46860282

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani. It is actually your own code that is blocking the event-loop. I suggest you search for "pyqt qthread" - there must be hundreds of examples and tutorials on this topic.